# Why manually creating a table picked up by Glue Crawler doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I tried to manually create a table in Glue Data Catalog, which was okay, but querying the table returned 0 results.

When I used Glue Crawler to pick up the same data and make the table metadata it worked and returned the data as expected.

So I generated the DDL from the working table, changed the name and ran the DDL to create a copy of the working table with a different name, but the new table now returned 0 results! Even though all I did was rename it. What's going on here?

Below is a copy of the DDL.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `hughnguyen_datastream_bucket2`(
  `id` int COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `price` double COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `product` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `timestamp` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `partition_0` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'paths'='id,price,product,timestamp') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://hughnguyen-datastream-bucket/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='testcrawler', 
  'averageRecordSize'='81', 
  'classification'='json', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'objectCount'='12', 
  'recordCount'='44', 
  'sizeKey'='3635', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you manually create partitioned table in Glue it will not be updated with partitions. Either you need to run `msck repair <table-name>` in Athena or run Glue crawler as mentioned in this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/tables-described.html#update-manual-tables).

In your other case when table created via Glue crawler it is automatically updated with partition info and hence you don't see this issue.

Comment: I get this error when running msck repair  -----
line 1:1: mismatched input 'msck'. Expecting: 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CALL', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DEALLOCATE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DROP', 'EXECUTE', 'EXPLAIN', 'GRANT', 'INSERT', 'PREPARE', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'UNLOAD', 'UPDATE', 'USE', <query>

Comment: nevermind i realised it has to be MSCK REPAIR TABLE  <table-name>, but even after running this the output is the same.

Comment: what is the s3 directory structure? Is it partition_0=values or S3://bucket/partitions_0 ? If it is later then you have to do alter table add partition https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html or run Glue crawler